# Power BI Custom Visual Parliament Chart

Tags: powerbi, reporting, deneb

I Have been given a project to produce a european parliament seating arrangement visual. I have tried to seart on the net without luck.
Can anyone sugest any custom visual that look like below?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck!. I have literally just produced something like this in [Deneb](https://deneb-viz.github.io/).

[image]

Full code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 550,
  "height": 300,
  "signals": [
    {"name": "dataLength", "update": "length(data('penguins'))"},
    {"name": "row0Radius", "value": 280},
    {"name": "row1Radius", "value": 260},
    {"name": "row2Radius", "value": 240},
    {"name": "row3Radius", "value": 220},
    {"name": "row4Radius", "value": 200},
    {"name": "row5Radius", "value": 180},
    {"name": "row6Radius", "value": 160},
    {"name": "row0Circ", "update": "PI*row0Radius"},
    {"name": "row1Circ", "update": "PI*row1Radius"},
    {"name": "row2Circ", "update": "PI*row2Radius"},
    {"name": "row3Circ", "update": "PI*row3Radius"},
    {"name": "row4Circ", "update": "PI*row4Radius"},
    {"name": "row5Circ", "update": "PI*row5Radius"},
    {"name": "row6Circ", "update": "PI*row6Radius"},
    {
      "name": "totalLength",
      "update": "row0Circ+row1Circ+row2Circ+row3Circ+row4Circ+row5Circ+row6Circ "
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "penguins",
      "url": "data/penguins.json",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "project", "fields": ["Species", "Island"]},
        {
          "type": "window",
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "fields": [null],
          "as": ["index"],
          "sort": {"field": "Island", "order": "ascending"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "placement",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "sequence",
          "start": 1,
          "stop": {"signal": "dataLength+1"},
          "as": "index"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "wholeCirc",
          "expr": "totalLength/dataLength"
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "fields": ["wholeCirc"],
          "as": ["cumWholeCirc"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "row",
          "expr": "datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ?0:datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ+row1Circ?1:datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ+row1Circ+row2Circ?2:datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ+row1Circ+row2Circ+row3Circ?3:datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ+row1Circ+row2Circ+row3Circ+row4Circ?4:datum.cumWholeCirc <row0Circ+row1Circ+row2Circ+row3Circ+row4Circ+row5Circ?5:6 "
        },
        {
          "type": "joinaggregate",
          "fields": ["Species"],
          "ops": ["count"],
          "groupby": ["row"],
          "as": ["rowCount"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "rowCirc",
          "expr": "datum.row==0?(row0Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==1?(row1Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==2?(row2Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==3?(row3Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==4?(row4Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==5?(row5Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):datum.row==6?(row6Circ/(datum.rowCount-1)):0"
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "fields": ["rowCirc"],
          "groupby": ["row"],
          "sort": {"field": "index", "order": "descending"},
          "as": ["cumRowCirc"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "cumRowCircAct",
          "expr": "datum.cumRowCirc - datum.rowCirc "
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "theta",
          "expr": "datum.cumRowCircAct==0?0:datum.row==0?(datum.cumRowCircAct/row0Radius):datum.row==1?(datum.cumRowCircAct/row1Radius):datum.row==2?datum.cumRowCircAct/row2Radius:datum.row==3?datum.cumRowCircAct/row3Radius:datum.row==4?datum.cumRowCircAct/row4Radius:datum.row==5?datum.cumRowCircAct/row5Radius:datum.row==6?datum.cumRowCircAct/row6Radius:0"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "x",
          "expr": "datum.row==0?row0Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==1?row1Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==2?row2Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==3?row3Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==4?row4Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==5?row5Radius*cos(datum.theta):datum.row==6?row6Radius*cos(datum.theta):0"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "y",
          "expr": "datum.row==0?row0Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==1?row1Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==2?row2Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==3?row3Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==4?row4Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==5?row5Radius*sin(datum.theta):datum.row==6?row6Radius*sin(datum.theta):0"
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {"field": "theta", "order": "ascending"},
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "fields": ["row_number"],
          "as": ["lookup"]
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "penguins",
          "key": "index",
          "fields": ["lookup"],
          "values": ["Island"],
          "as": ["finalIsland"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "linear",
      "round": true,
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"field": "x", "data": "placement"},
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "round": true,
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"field": "y", "data": "placement"},
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "placement", "field": "finalIsland"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category10"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "placement"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
          "shape": {"value": "circle"},
          "size": {"value": 130},
          "stroke": {"value": "#4682b4"},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "datum"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "finalIsland"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. where should i paste this code in power BI pbix

Comment: You need to download the Deneb custom visual and paste it in there. There will be some slight amendments you will need to make for your data.

Comment: @David - I have used your code but I am getting error. What changes do I need to make. I am using one column (Party) and a measure (count seat).


Error message I got:
Invalid specification {"$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json","data":[{"name":"penguins","transform":[{"fields":["Species","Island"],"type":"project"},{"as":["index"],"fields":[null],"ops":["row_number"],"sort":{"field":"Island","order":"ascending"},"type":"window"}],"url":"data/penguins.json"},{"name":"placement","transform":[{"as":"index","start":1,"stop":

Comment: You need to change the dataset within the spec. Have a look at  the docs for Deneb to understand how it all works.

Comment: You will also need to update the column/field references.

Comment: @David - I have tried to reference the dataset and column and measure but I am getting a blank canvas. I guess because I am new to Deneb and JSON. Please in the your code above, can you point the area or region I need to reference dataset, column and measure?

Comment: It is crucial your data is in the correct tabular format before adding to Deneb (non-aggregated). I suggest trying to make a simple bar chart using the tutorial to get the hang of things and make sure everything is working fine. To use my code, anywhere it says "penguins" should be replaced with "dataset". You can remove "Species" or replace it with your column used to colour the circles. Also, replace anything that says "Island" with the same column that will be used to colour code the circles.

Comment: Do you have test data you can post?

Comment: @David - Yes I have a test data. How can I share it

Comment: Upload a .pbix file somewhere and share a link by updating your question.

Comment: @David - This is the link to Test PBIX file
[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoVhy8hcwNisjnttouupPfQ7jt_t?e=bLkJi4)

Comment: I've looked at your .pbix and it seems to be working when I download it. What are you expecting to see that is not working? You seem to have 181 different parties over 6 years so not sure how you're planning to slice and filter this.

Comment: @David - I want to group the colors and slicer will by Year

Comment: That's my point. If you slice by year, some years only have two parties (2017) which is two circles which means a parliament chart is not suitable. And the colours are derived from party of which you have 181 different ones. Apologies but I'm not sure I understand your data.

Comment: @David - Thanks for explain. It make sense. Thank you for your time 